# Minio Gradle dependency android javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, minio

I have used following library in my android project.

> io.minio:minio:5.0.2

But getting following error while simple  compile / gradle sync and build apk.

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After analysing dependencies of MinIO Java sdk I found `com.google.code.findbugs` is causing this exception. as in below dependency graph of the MinIO java sdk.

```
 io.minio:minio:5.0.2
 +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-xml:1.20.0
 |    \--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0
 |         +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 3.0.2
 |         \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
 |              +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
 |              +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
 |              \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
 +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre
 |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
 |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0
 |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3
 |    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
 |    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
 +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0
 |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.12.0
 +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.12.0
 +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.7
 +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.6
 +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.6
 +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6
 |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0 -> 2.9.6
 |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.6
 +--- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1
 |    +--- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0
 |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 3.0.2
 \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 3.0.2
```

**Solution :** I excluded it from the gradle.

```
implementation ('io.minio:minio:5.0.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    exclude module: 'annotations'
}
```

Here is the MinIO Java sdk dependency graph After removing `com.google.code.findbugs`.

```
io.minio:minio:5.0.2
 +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-xml:1.20.0
 |    \--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0
 |         \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
 |              +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
 |              +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
 |              \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
 +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre
 |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.0.0
 |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3
 |    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
 |    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
 +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0
 |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.12.0
 +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.12.0
 +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.7
 +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.6
 +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.6
 \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6
      +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0 -> 2.9.6
      \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.6
```